# Python / PyWin32 / Script to run an excel macro not working

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, visual-studio-macros

This simple code is not working. I'm sure that the filepath is correct, but it seems that the problem is coming from a failure to open/add the workbook with the "Workbooks.Add" function.
Here's the code:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

#processing the results
excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Workbooks.Add('C:\\Documents and Settings\\dell600\\My Documents\\Webscraping Output\\Results\\Processed Results.xls')
excel.Run('Apply_Process')
excel.DisplayAlerts = 0
excel.Quit()
excel.DisplayAlerts = 0
```

Here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "TestMacro", line 6, in <module>
excel.Run('Apply_Process')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line282, in _ApplyTypes_
result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occured.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146771191), None)
```

Comment: You need to include the workbook name when calling `application.run`

Comment: See here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following:
   1) The right path, double check it, you also have to have the right extension 
   2) Make sure the file is open, I used excel.workbooks.Open(path)
   3) You need to have macros enabled in excel, if your running 2007 or later, you'll have to run a .xlsm